# I18N Using Django/Python

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Im looking to optimize our translation workflow for a django/python based project.
Currently we run a command to export our gettext files, send it to the translators, receive it back. Well you get the drill.

What in your opinion is the best way to optimize this workflow. Tools which integrate nicely and allow translations to be pushed and pulled from and to the system?

Options i've seen so far:

- http://trac.transifex.org/ (supported in django 1.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transifex was designed for pretty much this. It doesn't pull the strings from the project/app automatically yet, but it can be extended to do so if desired.

Answer (score -1):

Transifex has two ways to automate this: If your POT file is on a public server, you can setup a resource to auto-fetch the POT file frequently and update your resource.

The second option is to use the [client app](http://help.transifex.net/features/client/) and run it every time you build/deploy/commit.